# How trap expression that doesn't evaluate?

Tags: evaluation, error-trapping

If evaluating an expression produces an error, it's easy to trap that using `Check` or `Throw`...`Catch`.

How can one trap non-evaluation of an expression, that is, when the output is essentially the same as the input. For example, such an expression might be

```
 Integrate[(x + 1)^Sin[x], x]
```

which does partial evaluation (inside) but gives as output:

```
 Integrate[(1 + x)^Sin[x], x]
```

Comment: When you wrote "which does partial evaluation (inside)", did you mean that `x+1` changed to `1+x`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by the partial evaluation. I realize that complicates the situation. Perhaps a start would be the case where no such inside evaluation occurs.

Comment: I think the most practical would be to check if the head (`Integrate`) changes.  There are many functions which return unevaluated when they are unable to compute a result.  In all these cases the head will remain unchanged.  I think that in most use cases you will know beforehand if the function you are working with is one of these, thus this should be a good test.

Comment: First I wanted to suggest to do what `ValueQ` does, i.e. something like `SetAttributes[test, HoldAll]; test[expr_] := With[{result = expr}, {Hold[expr] =!= Hold[result], result}]`.  This tries to be very general but it won't handle that `x+1` → `1+x` thing.  But do we really need to be this general?  If we want to check if an `Integral` has computed, it's more robust to check if the head of the result is still `Integral`.  This presumes that we knew beforehand that we were working with `Integral` and not some arbitrary unknown expression.

Comment: Yes, checking whether the head remains unchanged will probably suffice Now I have to figure out how to do that!

Comment: Can you give a more practical example for an application?  I am thinking of a short but complete function with some input and output that needs to do this test inside.

Comment: This has come up often, and now I'm hard-pressed to find a "practical" example. Typically it's where one wants to use the solution of some equation as input to further computations but wants to abort in case *Mathematica* does not actually find any solution.

Comment: I mean, here's my example: `plotIntegral[expr_, x_] :=
 Module[{int},
  int = Integrate[expr, x];
  If[Head[int] === Integrate,
   $Failed,
   Plot[Evaluate[int], {x, 0, 1}]
   ]
  ]` . What I cannot figure out right now is in what situation you wouldn't know beforehand that you are working with `Integral` (or generally, some specific function).

Comment: @Szabolcs: Your `plotIntegral` is exactly the kind of situation I had in mind. Please make it into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: As further confirmation that @Szabolcs approach of cheching the returned head is very sound, a similar idea is found even in the documentation when an example snippet wants to automatically plot the numerical solution to an ODE, *but only if* `NDSolve` *executes successfully*. Look for `odeplot` in this page: http://wolfram.com/xid/0i6457z13po9yn453z0phv-cpt47o

Comment: @Szabolcs shouldn't that be an Answer?